# Use NLTK tokenizer in Keras workflow

Tags: machine-learning, keras, nlp, nltk

I am using the Keras tokenizer to tokenize sentences and than to create sequences of word indexes that I can use in the training of neural networks:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)
X_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
```

How can I use the casual_tokenize NLTK tokenizer to achieve a similar result? The NLTK toeknizer does not offer a texts_to_sequences() method.

Answer (score 1):

You can tokenized text with NLTK first. Then save tokens as a line with whitespace separator. Then use Keras Tokenizer as usual.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

X_train_tokenized = []
for test in X_train:
    X_train_tokenized.append(' '.join([token for token in word_tokenize(text)]))

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train_tokenized)
X_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train_tokenized)
```